# C++ Data Types Sizes/Ranges Display on Linux

Tags: c++, c, linux

I'm running Linux and frequently find myself wondering what the storage sizes and numeric ranges are for the basic data types (signed/unsigned char, signed/unsigned long, signed/unsigned long double, et cetera).

I'm hoping there's a little command line program which prints all this, though, if not, I realize that I could build it. (The `ascii` command, for instance, is very useful for a similar purpose.)

Comment: The exact sizes are implementation-dependent. Don't rely on them. If you want exact-width types, use `[u]intXX_t` from `stdint.h`.

Comment: Thanks, @CatPlusPlus, this is an issue I'm aware of, and one that I hope the command line program I'm envisioning would account for.

Comment: Try boost::integer it defines fixed width integer types that will be the same everywhere. Great for portability.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just vim through `limits.h`. For instance, on my machine it starts with:

```
/* Number of bits in a `char'.  */
#  define CHAR_BIT      8

/* Minimum and maximum values a `signed char' can hold.  */
#  define SCHAR_MIN     (-128)
#  define SCHAR_MAX     127
```

Or if you feel you need a separate program, build one that simply prints things like: `CHAR_BIT`, `SCHAR_MIN` etc.

Comment: cnicutar, one of the posters below suggests that the size is compiler dependent - are they wrong? Or is `limits.h` compiler-specific (which is fine)?

Comment: @Richard Yes, `limits.h` is compiler-specific.

Comment: Well, you seem to have offered the only command-line way of checking this, short of writing a program, which (as per comments below) seems difficult to do. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 1):

`sizeof(type)` returns the size of the type , basic or not.

Comment: I think you missed the point of the question; I am looking for a commandline utility which displays this information.

Answer (score 0):

If c++ take a look at std class [numeric_limits](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/limits/numeric_limits/)

Comment: I believe you may have missed the point of the question; I am looking for a commandline utility which displays this information.

Comment: A generic command line utility is unlikely to exist because it must be compiler specific. 
It is very easy to build one for a given compiler, just instantiate the std::numeric_limits with the desired type.

Comment: Ah, I would have thought that the size of integers, et cetera, would be machine-dependent, but what you say makes sense. You should update your answer to include this useful information - with sources, if possible.